# ExtJS 4 Grid unwanted scrolling on load and node selection

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a problem with the ExtJS 4 grid.  I am using ExtJS 4.2.1, and whenever I load data into my grid using the `loadRawData` function, it automatically scrolls to the bottom, or near the bottom.  Also, I am using grouping in the grid, and whenever I expand or collapse the node, it auto scrolls to the bottom again.  This is really frustrating, and I can't seem to find a solution.  I tried any solutions in [this post](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?133983-How-to-prevent-extjs-grid-from-scrolling-when-clicking-on-a-cell) from the Sencha forums, but nothing seemed to work.

This is my grid config:

```
gridPanel = new Ext.grid.Panel({
            header: false,
            title: 'Resultset',
            id: 'resultTable',
            width: 400,
            split: true,
            collapsible: true,
            collapseMode: 'mini',
            store: {
                model: 'resultset',
                autoLoad: false,
                pageSize: 100,
                proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    url: STORE_URL,
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: 'rows'
                    }
                },
                groupField:'tid'
            },
            features: [{ftype:'grouping'}],
            deferRowRender: false,
            columns: createColumns(),
            selModel: {
                checkOnly: true,
                moveEditorOnEnter: false,
                width: 20,
                mode: 'MULTI'
            },
            selType: 'rowmodel',
            tbar: [ createMenubar() ],
            bbar:[ createPagingBar() ],
            /*viewConfig: {
                preserveScrollOnRefresh: true
            }*/
        });
```

And then when I load the data, I just do something like this:

```
var store = gridPanel.getStore();
store.loadRawData(data, false);
```

Any help would be appreciated!